# How to estimate a critical value of Spearman's correlation for n=100?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spearman-rho

I have searched a lot, and I can only find tables that show critical values up to n=30. Can someone provide, or point me to, a simple method of estimating this value for different $\alpha$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For values over thirty the approximation (for a two-tailed test) is 
$$\frac{\Phi^{-1}\left(1-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$
so for example with $\alpha = 0.05$ and $n=100$ the numerator is about 1.96 and the denominator about 9.95, giving a critical value of about 0.197.

This comes from $\rho$ having approximately a normal distribution for large $n$, with mean $0$ and variance $1/(n − 1)$, assuming independence of the observations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a quotable source for this?

Comment: It seems to be standard in education, e.g. http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3LhPwUhrVIcC&pg=PA397 or http://www.umich.edu/~exphysio/MVS250/SpearmanRankCorr.doc

Answer (score 7):

See Wikipedia: [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient#Determining significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance):

"One can test for significance using
$$t = r \sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}},$$
which is distributed approximately as Student's $t$ distribution with $n − 2$ degrees of freedom under the null hypothesis."

Here $r$ is the sample estimate of Spearman's rank correlation coefficient. The reason critical values often aren't tabulated for $n > 30$ is that this approximation gets better as $n$ gets larger, and is very good for $n > 30$. The Stata statistical software package uses this formula to calculate $p$-values for *all* values of $n$.